# Python unittest how to have setUp and tearDown to run for each subtest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I would like to run the setUp() and the tearDown() function for each subtest in Python unit test. It works fine if I will call them explicitly, but is there any elegant way to do? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have test case with subtests looped over a list of variables. In the setUp and tearDown methods I have a test data setup which will be altered when the sub test is executed, so the sub test is failing for all except 1st value in the loop due to the test data got changed. So I want to run the setUp and tearDown for each sub test automatically.

Comment: @user1919581 could you add an example of subsets / tests with tiny logic? How it works? Do you need to run something once before each subset? Can you show just abstract example?

Comment: @user1919581 Have you found a solution yet? I'm wondering the same thing!

Comment: @Leoncino I did it by defining a separate method to do the tear down activity and calling that at the end of the every sub test. Couldn't find anything out of the box from the framework itself.